# Get source code for Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, source-code, source-packages

Where is the source code located for Ubuntu Server.  For instance, if the goal was to build it on a local machine?

As an example AWS Bottlerocket source code is on GitHub at URL: https://github.com/bottlerocket-os/bottlerocket

Is there a GitHub page for Ubuntu Server or Ubuntu Desktop source code?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "the source code"? The question of "how do I build an ISO image myself" is different than "what is the source of each package so I can compile every package from scratch"

Comment: "Source Code" is for thousands of packages.  There is not one "source code" source for this (linux kernel, DE components, SystemD, C libraries, etc. all have **different** source codes).  What exactly are you attempting to do here?

Comment: Yes, I am assuming the differentiation that Canonical provides is that they all this "package mess" usable.  They create copies of all of it, synchronize with the various open source projects, create daily build, and essentially organize all of it.

I would imagine that they would have a public GitHub page, but it looks like all this is done internally.

Answer (score 0):

The source code for Ubuntu is here: https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/source/ but I don't see a distinction between desktop and server - probably the source is common for both and depends on particular build configuration.

Comment: it is. Since before systemd even, The difference now is a systemd service using a different target and all differences are SETTINGS.

Comment: Clicking on "source" in the https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/source/ link keeps on appending "source" to the URL:
https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/source/source/
https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/source/source/source/
https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/source/source/source/source/

Comment: Click on the 1st date directory gives another source directory and it takes me to a Ubuntu page with Launchpad link:
https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/source/20230418/source/

Comment: The Launchpad link is non clickable. On the right to it and below it, are clickable links to six source DVDs.